# USP AND CTE Performance Issue IN SQL-SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, stored-procedures

May some one please help me to write better stored Procedure.

The code below took **3 hours** to run for 50 million records.

The below USP will do some computation, and I am trying to retain only those records with lowest NEWPRICE for same SKU.

Answer (score 1):

This is the query in your stored procedure:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 CMS INNER JOIN
     table2 CRT
     ON ID = ID CROSS APPLY
--------^
     (SELECT NEWS = (SPW - ((SPW * 15)/100))) AS C
```

If this query runs, then it is doing a `cross join`.  Why?  If there is an `id` column in both tables, then you would get an error (something about an ambiguous column reference).

I would recommend that you *always* use fully qualified column names -- that is, use the table alias for the table where the column comes from.

Comment: i have edited my question, the query is performing very bad. Please share your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can alter the procedure to return only the lowest `NEWPRICE` for each `SKU`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Usp_conditioncheck @mydate VARCHAR(50) 
AS 
    SELECT * INTO   mytable 
    FROM   (SELECT *, 
                   NEWPRICE =( spw - ( ( spw * 15 ) / 100 ) ), 
                   rn = Row_number()OVER (partition BY sku ORDER BY ( spw - ( ( spw * 15 ) / 100 ) ) ASC) 
            FROM   table1 CMS 
                   INNER JOIN table2 CRT 
                           ON id = id) A 
    WHERE  rn = 1
```

Now can just `Select` the table which will have lowest `NEWPRICE` for each `SKU`

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
```

Comment: May anyone please help me on this.